# a board game with a pirate skull?

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember playing it as a kid with my family (I’m 21 now)! It had a skull as the centerpiece & we remember there being plastic bones that would have either dots or numbers on them. You would maybe shake the bones in a cup and throw them out. I also remember there being eyeballs. There were different colored ones. I don’t really remember the object of the game.

Comment: Is there anything distinct about the game that has you recall it as a pirate skull? Was it a skull and crossbones for example? Did it have an eyepatch, or was the game otherwise somehow pirate themed?

Answer (score 4):

Is the game possibly [Tomb of Doom](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/5412/tomb-doom)?
[image]

Although it doesn't appear pirate themed, it does have bones with dots and eyeballs.
[image]